# Tuleap: display of project description

Tags: centos-6, tuleap

I entered a list in the description of my project with carriage return after each item of the list. However in the project page, when Tuleap displays the descritpion of the project, it suppressed the carriage returns.

For example if my project description is the following:

```
My project description:
- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
```

Tuleap displays this:

```
My project description: - item 1 - item 2 - item 3
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tuleap will not automatically convert newlines to HTML br in project description.
However you can add some HTML AFAIR (cannot test right now) so UL/LI should works here